# How to get the right simulation in R

Tags: r

Question:
Suppose the numbers in the following random number table correspond to people arriving for   work at a large factory. Let 0,1,and 2 be smokers and 3-9 be nonsmokers. After many   arrivals, calculate the total relative frequency of smokers .

here is my R code to simulate the total relative frequency of smokers.

```
simulation<-function(k){
    x<-round(runif(k)*10)
    return  (length(x[x<3])/k)}

> simulation(100)
[1] 0.27
> simulation(1000)
[1] 0.244
> simulation(10000)
[1] 0.2445
> simulation(100000)
[1] 0.24923
```

Why i can't get the result 0.3?

Comment: Because the expected value of your simulation is actually .25.

Comment: why?i think it is 3/10=0.3

Comment: Because you're rounding.  Think of which values generated by by runif after you multiply by 10 will round to a value less than 3

Comment: How to fix my code to get the right answer?

Comment: replace `round` with `floor` but Dason's answer is a much better rewrite of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all you want to do is get a discrete uniform distribution on the numbers 0, 1, ..., 9 then just use sample

```
sample(0:9, k, replace = TRUE)
```

With the code you have right now you'll actually get a probability of .05 each of getting 0 or 10 and a probability of .10 each of getting 1-9.